# Associated replicated vectors in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with values in several vectors that I want replicated based on the values in adjacent vectors as so:

```
Rep Beaker Ndev days
1   1      2    4
1   1      3    6
1   2      1    6
1   2      2    8
```

I can create a new replicated data frame using `rep(df$days, times = df$Ndev)` where `df` is the data frame to get the number of times that a certain day is experienced by my treatment organisms. I would like to also make sure that the relevant `Rep` and `Beaker` values follow the replicated days. For example:

```
Rep Beaker days
1   1      4
1   1      4
1   1      6
1   1      6
1   1      6
1   2      6
1   2      8
1   2      8
```

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (where `df` is your data frame):

```
df[rep(seq(nrow(df)), df$Ndev),]

#    Rep Beaker Ndev days
#1     1      1    2    4
#1.1   1      1    2    4
#2     1      1    3    6
#2.1   1      1    3    6
#2.2   1      1    3    6
#3     1      2    1    6
#4     1      2    2    8
#4.1   1      2    2    8
```

The idea is to repeat the row indices as many as `Ndev`.

Comment: Thats it! Thanks for the help!